# .NET 3.5 DotNetZip Problems searching through extracted files

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetzip

I have zip files I need to search through I have working code for .NET 4.5 using System.IO.Compression and it works flawlessly but I can't seem to get it to work using DotNetZip in .NET 3.5

Here is my code

```
di = new DirectoryInfo(sFullLogPath + "\\");
                files = di.GetFiles(sExtension);
                logs.Info("Searching " + sType + " logs on  " + sDate + " for " + sSearchTerm);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                try
                {
                    foreach(var file in files)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);
                        using (ZipFile archive = ZipFile.Read(sFullLogPath + "\\" + file.Name))
                        {
                            foreach(var entry in archive)
                            {
                                if(entry.FileName.EndsWith(".ininlog",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                {
                                    //Console.WriteLine(entry.FileName);
                                    try
                                    {
                                        Directory.CreateDirectory(sTemp);
                                        entry.Extract(Path.Combine(sTemp, entry.FileName));
                                        Stream streamTemp = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                                        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(streamTemp);
                                        string line;
                                        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                                        {
                                            if (line.Contains(sSearchTerm))
                                            { logs.Info("{0} contains \"{1}\"", file.Name, sSearchTerm); break; }
                                            else
                                            { Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; Console.WriteLine("{0} does not contain \"{1}\"", file.Name, sSearchTerm); Console.ResetColor(); break; }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ae)
                                    {
                                        logs.Error(ae.Message);
                                    }
                                    catch (SystemException se)
                                    {
                                        logs.Error(se.Message);
                                    }
                                    catch (ApplicationException ape)
                                    {
                                        logs.Error(ape.Message);
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e)
                                    {
                                        logs.Error(e.Message);
                                    }
                                    finally
                                    {
                                        Directory.Delete(sTemp, true);
                                        archive.Dispose();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ae)
                {
                    logs.Error(ae.Message);
                }
                catch (SystemException se)
                {
                    logs.Error(se.Message);
                }
                catch (ApplicationException ape)
                {
                    logs.Error(ape.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    logs.Error(e.Message);
                }
```

Expected Behavior:

Each zipped file in a directory is unzipped to a temporary location then searched to see if the string is in that file, if found it will output the name of the file it was found in

Current Behavior:

Not finding and referencing to the string I am looking for even though I know it's there and it works fine with the .NET 4.5 version on the same file

Why don't I use .NET 4.5, we have custom software on our servers and it currently has issues with .NET 4.5
[image: .NET 4.5 Version using System.IO.Compression]
[image: .NET 3.5 Version Using DotNetZip]

Fixed code thanks to @Thomas - looks like the else was causing the false positive

```
else { Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; Console.WriteLine("{0} does not contain \"{1}\"", file.Name, sSearchTerm); Console.ResetColor(); break; }
```

Here is the fixed code

```
di = new DirectoryInfo(sFullLogPath + "\\");
                files = di.GetFiles(sExtension);
                logs.Info("Searching " + sType + " logs on  " + sDate + " for " + sSearchTerm);
                Console.WriteLine("");
                try
                {
                    foreach(var file in files)
                    {
                        //Console.WriteLine(file.Name);
                        using (ZipFile archive = ZipFile.Read(file.FullName))
                        {
                            foreach(var entry in archive)
                            {
                                if(entry.FileName.EndsWith(".ininlog", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        using (var tempStream = entry.OpenReader())
                                        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(tempStream))
                                        {
                                            string line;
                                            while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                                            {
                                                if(line.Contains(sSearchTerm))
                                                {
                                                    logs.Info("{0} contains \"{1}\"", file.Name, sSearchTerm);
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ae)
                                    {
                                        logs.Error(ae.Message);
                                    }
                                    catch (SystemException se)
                                    {
                                        logs.Error(se.Message);
                                    }
                                    catch (ApplicationException ape)
                                    {
                                        logs.Error(ape.Message);
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception e)
                                    {
                                        logs.Error(e.Message);
                                    }
                                    finally
                                    {
                                        archive.Dispose();
                                        //Directory.Delete(sTemp + "\\" + entry.FileName);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ae)
                {
                    logs.Error(ae.Message);
                }
                catch (SystemException se)
                {
                    logs.Error(se.Message);
                }
                catch (ApplicationException ape)
                {
                    logs.Error(ape.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    logs.Error(e.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    //
                }
                break;
```

Comment: You should debug your code and figure out whether the problem is with compression/decompression part or searching. Also look like Thomas Levesque answer show the problem (as you trying to search ZIP as text file for string).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're opening the wrong file here:

```
Stream streamTemp = new FileStream(file.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
```

`file` is the ZIP file, not the file you just extracted.

BTW, I don't think you need to extract the files, DotNetZip <strike>probably</strike> allows you to write the uncompressed stream directly.

---

EDIT: I just checked: you can use the `OpenReader` method to get a stream to read the uncompressed content of the entry. Just create the `StreamReader` around that stream; no need to actually extract the file.

```
...
try
{
    using (var stream = entry.OpenReader())
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains(sSearchTerm))
            { logs.Info("{0} contains \"{1}\"", file.Name, sSearchTerm); break; }
            else
            { Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red; Console.WriteLine("{0} does not contain \"{1}\"", file.Name, sSearchTerm); Console.ResetColor(); break; }
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: I don't want to run this in a stream as the servers the logs are on are in production and I am trying to limit the memory / resources being used most of the logs are 2 GB each, that is why I was extracting to a temporary location

Comment: @ondrovic, reading the stream directly from the zip doesn't load the whole file in memory; the data is uncompressed on demand when you read the stream, and isn't kept in memory (except the part that's in the StreamReader's buffer, but that's typically pretty small)

Comment: I guess I am not following could you provide an example of how to do what you are talking about ?

Comment: got it working looks like it was my else statement causing some issues